# googleapi: Error 404: No bot associated with this project., notFound

Tags: go, google-app-engine-golang

```
msgService := chat.NewSpacesMessagesService(service)
    msg := ChatCard("Title", "Subtitle", data)
    // msg := "hello"
    fmt.Print("Now ChatCard Method called\n")
    _, err = msgService.Create("spaces/AAAAwlgqHZg", msg).Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

*I'm going to connect to google chat But a google API error occurs, Any help would be appreciatable?*

Comment: Hi, please let me know if my answer helped. If this answered your question you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so this can help other people in the community who may have the same concern as you.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You need to go to your GCP project's Chat API [configuration page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat) to fill out the Application info and then publish it.

**Long answer:** The error message `404: "No bot associated with this project."` is mentioned in Google's issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131126985). The explanation is that you need to first configure your "bot". The point is that the Chat API methods act through chatbots. These show up in the rooms with the `BOT` tag and the API works as if the bots are users performing the actions.

[image]

Nowadays Google has changed their wording and they no longer refer to this as a "bot", now it's simply referred to as "app", but for all intents and purposes the process is the same. You need to go to the Chat API's [configuration page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat) in your GCP project to establish its name, avatar image, etc.

[image]

The app also needs to be published to the Google Workspace Marketplace either publicly or for your domain's users so they can interact with it. I recommend you check out their full documentation:

- [About chat bots/chat apps](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/apps-publish#enable_the_google_chat_api)
- [Configuring the app](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/apps-publish#enable_the_google_chat_api)